# IMAP incoming mail server setup in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, imap

I have searched and read so many questions regarding this. I am saving incoming emails in to a MySQL database.
I am using pipe to script method and I have already set up those things and the file reads correctly when I receive an email.

The error I receive is:

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to server: ' . imap_last_error());
```

I am confused with $hostname variable, I have tried many times and I failed.

Normally my server is localhost for MySQL. I tried with that, and my server uses SSL. I used this `localhost:993/imap/ssl}INBOX`, but none are working. What is the correct server for that variable?

```
imap.mydomain.org:993 ???
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. I am fed up with this.

Comment: Host name should be `imap.maydomain.org`

Comment: Hi,
error : 
Cannot connect to SERVER: Can't open mailbox {imap.example.org: invalid remote specification
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going by what you have said, have you tried:

```
{localhost:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
```

or

```
{imap.mydomain.org:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
```

If that doesn't work, could you try providing an error output?

Comment: Hi there,
This is the error message I got when I use {imap.mydomain.org:993/imap/ssl}INBOX

Cannot connect to SERVER: Certificate failure for mail.mywebsite.org: self signed certificate: /CN=server01.lycahost.com/emailAddress=ssl@server01.lycahost.com

Answer (score 0):

The true error message is **Certificate failure**, as mentioned by OP.

To solve the issue, change the function to:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{imap.maydomain.org:993/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'user@domain.com', 'userpass') or die('Cannot connect to server: ' . imap_last_error());
```

to bypass validating self-signed certificate.